# Minimum and Maximum from user inputs

Tags: python-2.7

The program below takes user inputs and output the minimum and maximum from the numbers input but it is always printing "none" and I can't find anything wrong with it (obviously I am missing something). Anybody can help me to understand what's wrong.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num1 = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num1 == "done" : break

    try:
        num=int(num1)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
        continue

        if smallest is None or num < smallest:
            smallest = num

        if largest is None or num > largest:
            largest = num

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Comment: Proper indentation is vital in Python. Check yours.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statements were indented too far.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num1 = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num1 == "done" : break

    try:
        num=int(num1)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
        continue

    if smallest is None or num < smallest:
        smallest = num

    if largest is None or num > largest:
        largest = num

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I appreciate your help. I will be very careful with the indentation henceforth.